# Android resource linking failed after updated

Tags: android, android-studio, reference

After updated Android Studio 3.0 to 3.2.1 I replaced compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion and all implemention from 26 to 28. And when i need to build project i have error, like as

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:241412: error: expected dimension but got (raw string) 20.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\674dd2eb2f75b740f6360fb0ac412dcd\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.user.myproject\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

At the version 27 it worked, but at the 28 does'nt work.
I tried clean and rebuild project, also tried invalidate cashes and restart, but it is nothing to help me.
I cannot understand, in which file i have error.

Comment: "expected dimension but got string" check your dimens xml file

Comment: @OussemaAroua Of course i checked this

Comment: Can you post what's in line (oh god) 241412 of C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml ?

Comment: i solved it, it was problem in my style.xml.